# rails form with no attachment to a model or link

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a 3 input form that the inputs will only be used to run a calculation in javascript for a modal on the same page. How should I call the form if it doesn't really need to go anywhere. I just need the inputs and the button to call the modal. Here is what i have, it works but not sure if my syntax is correct.

```
  <%= form_tag( '/welcome/index', post: true, remote: true) do %>

    <h5 class="label">Estimated new home cost?</h5>
    <%= text_field_tag :price, nil, placeholder: "ex. 100,000", class: "form-control form-control-lg", id: 'price' %>

    <h5 class="label">Estimated payment for a new home?</h5>
    <%= text_field_tag :mortgage, nil, placeholder: "ex. 1,200", class: "form-control form-control-lg", id: 'mortgage' %>

    <h5 class="label">Current Monthly Rent?</h5>
    <%= text_field_tag :rent, nil, placeholder: "ex. 800", class: "form-control form-control-lg", id: 'rent' %>


    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#savingsModal">
      See how quickly you can buy a home
    </button>
```

Comment: I don't think you need to specify id like `id: 'price'`, the text field tag helper will generate id `price`, `mortgage` and `rent`

Comment: @RaviMariya You are right, it did generate the id. Thanks

Comment: you can also use rails link_to instead of HTML button `<%= link_to 'See how quickly you can buy a home', '#', data: {toggle: 'modal', target: '#savingsModal'}, class: 'btn btn-success btn-lg' %>`, also i don't know about post: true, but you can change it to `method: :post`, everything else looks fine

Comment: @RaviMariya so the form_tag just pointing back to the same page is fine?

Comment: yes its fine, also if you don't specify any action in your form, it will submit it on the same page like `<% form_tag remote: true do %>` will submit the form on the same page from which it is called, you don't need to specify any action name, so you can remove it

Comment: sorry it should be `<%= form_tag '', data: {remote: true} do %>` if you want it to be a ajax request

Comment: Still on the same task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form data doesn't have be sent to the server, simply don't use the form tag. You can use the `text_field_tag` and button with the form_tag around them.

One advice on that h5 tag that you use, replace it with a proper label tag, it is simply better as satisfies accessibility requirements: Use it like one of the following two

```
<%= label_tag for: 'price', 'Estimated new home cost?' %>

<label>Estimated new home cost?
<%= text_field_tag :price, nil, placeholder: "ex. 100,000", class: "form-control form-control-lg" %>
```

Comment: But I want the label to be larger. How do I account for that css on the label?

Comment: `label { font-size: 200%; }`